# I am confused about the smoke tests in automation

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have been thinking about this and know what a smoke test is by definition but I am still not able to wrap my head around this.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this and maybe give a real use case or example.

I am confused about the part when ppl say to smoke test is to check major functionalities, what are major functionalities?

So if I have about 100 test cases (e2e) and have 5 tests related to component x how do I decide how many tests to run(smoke test) against the component x (major functionalities) it seems everything is major functionalities for me or I can run all the 5 tests.

Then isn't every individual test a smoke test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question might be better asked on [sqa](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/) or even [softwareengineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). but....

"You're sniffing for smoke to detect if there is a fire"

The short answer is: **smoke testing is whatever tests you feel you need to run to initially move forward with further testing**. In my experience it's going to be different for everyone.

Here is an example: in my case, I know I always need to check this one specific aspect of our app because it breaks a lot and it affects 75% of the application so I always run a few tests against that feature first before running the whole regression.

To directly answer your question about 'major functionalities'; a good example of that would be login.  My app requires all users login with username and password. I would consider that "major functionality" since everything else a user does is dependent on logging in to work properly.  There is very little point to me testing some other feature if login testing were broken.

Comment: _You're sniffing for smoke to detect if there is a fire_: Great words !!!